# Account Name not displaying automatically when lead is converting in lightning

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration, lightning, admin

I am not able to see the Account Name and Opportunity Name at the time of converting lead in lightning. But it is these are coming automatically when I am using salesforce classic version.
Please help me how to display those are automatically.

Thanks
Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

Not populating the account name is currently a frustrating limitation of the Lightning experience. This issue is raised with salesforce and they are likely to fix this in time. But it's slow progress.

Opportunity names can be decided on conversion. It doesn't pre populate the name so you have more flexibility to decide.